# enable gpu support in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, gpu, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to enable GPU on Sagemaker notebook. Although I am using an ml.p2.xlarge instance, when I try this in my notebook:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
```

the output is `False`. Without a GPU, my training process will be pretty slow. How exactly can I activate and use the GPU in my Sagemaker notebook?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using an `_amazonei_` kernel in the Notebook? try using a different kernel, for example `conda_tensorflow*`

Kernels that have `amazonei` in their name are not GPU compatible, they are for used with [Amazon Elastic Inference Accelerator.](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/elastic-inference/)

- **Note 1** the P2 uses an old-generation K80 GPU ; you can access something more recent (and cheaper) in SageMaker Studio: the G4
  notebook (that has a T4 card)
- **Note 2** according to [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available), the function you use is deprecated. Once you are on a GPU-compatible kernel, TF recommends
  using `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`